# Is code in episode 1 of New Game 2 actually an infinite loop?

Tags: new-game

In episode 1 of New Game 2, around 9:40, there is a shot of the code that Nene has written:

[image]

Here is it in text form with the comments translated:

```
// the calculation of damage when attacked
void DestructibleActor::ReceiveDamage(float sourceDamage) 
{
    // apply debuffs
    auto resolvedDamage = sourceDamage;
    for (const auto& debuf:m_debufs)
    {
        resolvedDamage = debuf.ApplyToDamage(resolvedDamage);
        m_currentHealth -= resolvedDamage
        if (m_currentHealth <= 0.f)
        {
            m_currentHealth = 0.f;
            DestroyMe();
        }
    }
}
```

After the shot, Umiko, pointing at the for loop, said that the reason why the code crashed is that there is an infinite loop.

I don't really know C++ so I'm not sure whether what she is saying is true.

From what I can see, the for loop is just iterating through the debufs that the Actor currently has. Unless the Actor has an infinite amount of debufs, I don't think it can possibly become an infinite loop.

But I'm not sure because the only reason that there is a shot of the code is that they wanted to put an easter egg here, right? We would have just gotten a shot of the back of the laptop and heard Umiko saying "Oh you've got an infinite loop there". The fact that they actually showed some code makes me think that somehow the code is an easter egg of some sort.

Will the code actually create an infinite loop?

Comment: Probably helpful: [additional screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/0XQKR4G.png) of Umiko saying that "It was *calling the same operation* over and over again", which might not be shown in the code.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that! @AkiTanaka the sub that I watched says "infinite loop"

Comment: it could be a stackoverflow then coz we don't know if DestroyMe isn't calling ReceiveDamage

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question purely about programming which does not require any context or knowledge of the source anime/manga to answer, as per https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/669.

Comment: @LoganM I don't really agree. It's not just that OP has a question about some source code that happened to come from an anime; OP's question is about a particular statement made _about_ the source code by a character in the anime, and there is an anime-related answer, namely "Crunchyroll done goofed and mistranslated the line".

Comment: @senshin I think you're reading what you want the question to be about, rather than what is actually asked. The question provides some source code and asks whether it generates an infinite loop as real-life C++ code. *New Game!* is a fictional work; there is no need for code presented in it to conform to real-life standards. What Umiko says about the code is more authoritative than any C++ standards or compilers. The top (accepted) answer has no mention of any in-universe information. I think an on-topic question could be asked about this with a good answer, but as phrased this isn't it.

Comment: @LoganM I agree about [not requiring context/knowledge of the source anime/manga to answer]. I haven't even watched the show yet. Not sure it'd be fully on-topic in gamedev.SE either as it's entirely **fictional**. It's arguably off-topic unless  "Historical or societal context of an anime or manga", or "Plot, character, or **setting explanations**", gets expanded/stretched a bit.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The code is not an infinite loop but it is a bug.

There's two (possibly three) issues:

- If no debufs are present no damage will be applied at all
- Excessive damage will be applied if there is more than 1 debuf
- If DestroyMe() immediately deletes the object and there are still m_debufs to be processed the loop will be executing over a deleted object and trashing memory. Most game engines have a destroy queue to work around this and more so that may not be an issue.

The application of damage should be outside the loop.

Here's the corrected function:

```
// the calculation of damage when attacked
void DestructibleActor::ReceiveDamage(float sourceDamage) 
{
    // apply debuffs
    auto resolvedDamage = sourceDamage;
    for (const auto& debuf:m_debufs)
    {
        resolvedDamage = debuf.ApplyToDamage(resolvedDamage);
    }
    m_currentHealth -= resolvedDamage
    if (m_currentHealth <= 0.f)
    {
        m_currentHealth = 0.f;
        DestroyMe();
    }
}
```

Comment: The corrected code also does show up towards the end of that segment, too.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128609/discussion-on-answer-by-stephane-hockenhull-is-code-in-episode-1-of-new-game-2-a).

Answer (score 7):

The code does not seem to create an infinite loop.

The only way the loop would be infinite would be if

```
debuf.ApplyToDamage(resolvedDamage);
```

or

```
DestroyMe();
```

were to add new items to the `m_debufs` container.

This seems unlikely. And if it were the case, the program could crash because of changing the container while being iterated.

The program would most likely crash because of the call to `DestroyMe();` which presumably destroys the current object that is currently running the loop.

We can think of it as the cartoon where the 'bad guy' saws a branch to have the 'good guy' fall with it, but realizes too late that he's on the wrong side of the cut. Or the Midgaard Snake eating it's own tail.

---

I should also add that the most common symptom of an infinite loop is that it freezes the program or makes it not responsive. It will crash the program if it allocates memory repeatedly, or does something that ends up dividing by zero, or the likes.

---

Based on the comment by [Aki Tanaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2516/aki-tanaka) ,

> Probably helpful: [additional screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5vHa.jpg) of Umiko saying that "It was calling the same operation over and over again", which might not be shown in the code.

*"It was calling the same operation over and over again"* This is more likely.

Assuming that `DestroyMe();` is not designed to be called more than once, it is more likely to cause a crash.

A way to fix this issue would be to change the `if` for something like this:

```
    if (m_currentHealth <= 0.f)
    {
        m_currentHealth = 0.f;
        DestroyMe();
        break;
    }
```

This would exit the loop when the DestructibleActor is destroyed, making sure that 1) the `DestroyMe` method is called only once and 2) don't apply buffs uselessly once the object is already considered dead.

Comment: Breaking out of the for loop when health <= 0 is definitely a better fix than waiting until after the loop to check health.

Comment: I think I'd probably `break` out of the loop, and _then_ call `DestroyMe()`, just to be safe

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with the code:

1. If there are no debufs, no damage would be taken.
2. `DestroyMe()` function name sounds dangerous. Depending on how its implemented, it might or might not be an issue. If it's just a call to the destructor of the current object wrapped in a function, then there is an issue, as the object would be destroyed in the middle of it executing code. If it's a call to a function which queues the deletion event of the current object, then there is no issue, as the object would be destroyed after it completes its execution and the event loop kicks in.
3. The actual issue that seems to be mentioned in the anime, the "It was calling the same operation over and over again" -- it will call `DestroyMe()` as long as `m_currentHealth <= 0.f` and there are more debuffs left to iterate, which might result in `DestroyMe()` being called multiple times, over and over again. The loop should stop after the first `DestroyMe()` call, because deleting an object more than once results in memory corruption, which will likely result in a crash in the long run.

I'm not really sure why every debuf takes away the health, instead of the health being taken away only once, with the effects of all debuffs being applied on the initial damage taken, but I will assume that's the correct game logic.

The correct code would be

```
// the calculation of damage when attacked
void DestructibleActor::ReceiveDamage(float sourceDamage) 
{
    // apply debuffs
    auto resolvedDamage = sourceDamage;
    for (const auto& debuf:m_debufs)
    {
        resolvedDamage = debuf.ApplyToDamage(resolvedDamage);
        m_currentHealth -= resolvedDamage
        if (m_currentHealth <= 0.f)
        {
            m_currentHealth = 0.f;
            DestroyMe();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should point out that as I have written memory allocators in the past, deleting the same memory doesn't have to be an issue. It could also be redundant. It all depends on the allocator's behavior. Mine just acted like a low level linked list so the "node" for the deleted data either gets set as free several times or redeleted several times (which would just correspond to redundant pointer redirections). Good catch though.

Comment: Double-free is a bug, and generally leads to undefined behavior and crashes. Even if you have a custom allocator that somehow disallows reuse of the same memory address, double-free is a smelly code as it makes no sense and you will get yelled at by static code analyzers.

Comment: Of course! I didn't design it for that purpose. Some languages just require an allocator due to lacks of features. No no no. I was merely stating that a crash isn't guaranteed. Certain design classifications don't always crash.